# Travel by train in the UK using my senior railcard

Tags: uk, trains, senior-travel

My senior railcard has expired. Can I renew this or just apply for a new card? The card expired several years ago!

Answer (score 3):

At this point, you would have to purchase a new one, as it can only be [renewed when it's within one month of its expiry date](https://www.senior-railcard.co.uk/using-your-railcard/renewing-your-railcard/).

> [Where to buy - Senior Railcard](https://www.senior-railcard.co.uk/using-your-railcard/where-to-buy/):
>
> Three easy ways to buy...
>
> 1 Year Senior Railcard: £30 Online, At a Station, By Phone
>   3-Year Senior Railcard: £70 Online only
>
> **[Online](https://secure.senior-railcard.co.uk/login-or-register?)**
>
> You can save yourself time by [buying your Senior Railcard online](https://secure.senior-railcard.co.uk/login-or-register?). The only things you’ll need are:
>
> - A valid passport number or UK driving licence
> - A debit or credit card
>
> **What happens next?**
>
> We aim to dispatch your Railcard within one working day of you ordering it, but it’s probably best to allow up to five working days for your Senior Railcard to arrive. It’ll be sent out free of charge by First Class post, but if you prefer, you have the option to pay for Special Delivery.
>
> **At a Staffed Station Ticket Office**
>
> You can buy a Senior Railcard at any staffed station ticket office or National Rail-licensed Travel Agent. The main advantage of this is that you can do it on the day you are travelling. To save time, it’s a good idea to fill in the application form before you get there.
>
> If you're applying at a station for the first time you'll need to complete an application form which is also available here and you’ll need to bring one of the following:
>
> - Your birth certificate
> - Passport (all nationalities accepted)
> - UK driving licence
>
> Once you've bought your Railcard at a station, you can then register it online. This will make it easier for you to renew or buy other cards online.
>
> If you are renewing your Railcard, you will need to fill in the application form, and show your existing Railcard. This is automatically accepted as proof of your age.
>
> If you do not have any of the above forms of identification you can call our telesales service, who will check your eligibility against the electoral roll.
>
> **By Phone**
>
> You can get your Railcard quickly and easily over the phone too. Simply call our telesales service on 0345 3000 250 (0700-2200 every day, except Christmas Day. Calls are charged at the national rate).